# Can't Reference Portable Class Library Project Xamarin.iOS

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin

When I try to add a portable class library in Visual Studio, it only gives me an option for "Xamarin.iOS (Classic)" and not "Xamarin.iOS". So when I try to add the project as a reference to my ios project, I'm unable to add a reference from a none classic ios app to a portable library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PCLs are supported for both iOS Classic and iOS Unified.

On the Mac the PCL profiles are installed with Mono 3.10.

On Windows the PCL profiles for iOS Unified are not installed by default since they require a new version of NuGet 2.8.3 which is currently available as an alpha release. To get the PCL profiles for iOS Unified there is a separate installer which will install NuGet 2.8.3 into Visual Studio and install the PCL profiles.

There is a blog post about what iOS Unified is compared with iOS Classic.

[Found the answer here](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/25876/xamarin-ios-support-for-portable-class-libraries-pcl) Thanks Matt Ward